# c++ primer - value of variables

Tags: c++

I started reading *C++ Primer, 5th Edition* and I'm having troubles understanding one thing when it comes to `std::cin`.

The following is the code they present as their example. The idea behind it is that a bookstore is recording its transactions and the program should be able to sum back-to-back transactions as long as they belong to the same book (ie, they have the same isbn).

I haven't included the header file since I believe it isn't relevant to my question. In case it's actually needed, you can find it [here](https://github.com/courri/Cpp-Primer-5th-Edition/blob/master/1/Sales_item.h).

My issue with the example is that the comments explaining the code say that the first `Sales_item` object, named `total`, is used to store the current transaction, while the one named `trans` is used to 'hold the running sum'. That is, the *total*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main() 
{
    Sales_item total; // variable to hold data for the next transaction

    // read the first transaction and ensure that there are data to process
    if (std::cin >> total) {
        Sales_item trans; // variable to hold the running sum
        // read and process the remaining transactions
        while (std::cin >> trans) {
            // if we're still processing the same book
            if (total.isbn() == trans.isbn()) 
                total += trans; // update the running total 
            else {              
                // print results for the previous book 
                std::cout << total << std::endl;  
                total = trans;  // total now refers to the next book
            }
        }
        std::cout << total << std::endl; // print the last transaction
    } else {
        // no input! warn the user
        std::cerr << "No data?!" << std::endl;
        return -1;  // indicate failure
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've seen various examples with this kind of reasoning, and to me it looks counterintuitive. Shouldn't the first variable be holding the total (since it belongs to a wider scope and it's named, you know, `total`) while the second holds the current transaction? Did I understand this completely backwards and the second `cin` is actually holding the total?

Comment: _"I haven't included the header file since I believe it isn't relevant to my question. In case it's actually needed, you can find it here."_ Abstract it away so that your question contains a self-contained [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, the comments appear to be swapped. They should be:

```
Sales_item total; // variable to hold the running sum
Sales_item trans; // variable to hold data for the next transaction
```